# List with fast contains

Tags: java, list, set

I wonder if there's a `List` implementation allowing fast `contains`. I'm working with quite a long `List` and I can't switch to `Set` since I need the access by index. I can ignore the performance, which may be acceptable now and may or may not be acceptable in the future. I can create a `HashSet` and do all modifying operations on both, but doing it manually is quite boring and error prone.

I know that it's impossible to have a class working like both `List` and `Set` (because of the different `equals` semantics), but I wonder if there's `List` implementing `RandomAccess` and employing an `HashSet` for speeding up `contains`.

Comment: a hash list should be fast but it is not part of standard JAVA API

Comment: Could you maintain your list sorted and use binary search for contains?

Comment: He requires random access by index which would not possible if the index changes on insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap a list and hashSet that combines best of both worlds

```
public class FastContainsList<T> extends AbstractSequentialList<T> implements RandomAccess{
//extending sequential because it bases itself of the ListIterator(int) and size() implementation

    private List<T> list=new ArrayList<T>();
    private Set<T> set=new HashSet<T>();


    public int size(){
        return list.size();
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o){//what it's about
        return set.contains(o);
    }

    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int i){
        return new ConIterator(list.listIterator(i));
    }

    /*for iterator()*/
    private ConIterator implements ListIterator<T>{

        T obj;
        ListIterator<T> it;

        private ConIterator(ListIterator<T> it){
        this.it = it
        }

        public T next(){
        return obj=it.next();
        }

        public T previous(){
        return obj=it.previous();
        }

        public void remove(){
        it.remove();//remove from both
        set.remove(obj);
        }

        public void set(T t){
            it.set(t);
            set.remove(obj);
            set.add(obj=t);
        }

         public void add(T t){
             it.add(t);
             set.add(t);
         }

        //hasNext and hasPrevious + indexes still to be forwarded to it
    }

}
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a "prefabricated solution", a library providing a well tested class. But it doesn't seem to exists, so I accept your answer.

Comment: This implementation _will create problems_ if your `FastContainsList` contains two times the same element and you use `remove(.)` on it.  Your internal set will not contain the element any longer while your internal list still does.  E.g. `fcl.add("a"); fcl.add("a"); fcl.remove("a");` Now `fcl`'s internal list still contains "a", while the set doesn't.  I.e., `fcl.contains("a");` will wrongly return `false`.

Comment: @dotwin if you need to allow doubles then you change the HashSet to a `HashMap<T, Integer>` and keep track of how many times T is in the list and if you remove the last one you remove from the map.

Comment: I agree with @dotwin, however it is a solution that could be used in the right circumstances. I suppose a check could be added to ensure the list and set are in sync. It would simply need to ensure that the set.size() and list.size() are the same after an add/remove operation.

Comment: @mrswadge For minimal effort you can either disallow duplicates or keep track of how many of each item is in the list (which you can do with a `Map<T, Integer>`)

Comment: @ratchetfreak I agree with your Map idea - it's an option. Having read the javadocs, it seems your implementation goes against the advice. `This [AbstractSequentialList] class provides a skeletal implementation of the List interface to minimize the effort required to implement this interface backed by a "sequential access" data store (such as a linked list). For random access data (such as an array), AbstractList should be used in preference to this class.` So, I feel I should ask why you used AbstractSequentialList over AbstractList as you are implementing the RandomAccess interface.

Comment: I found it easier to implement remove and add using the ListIterator of the top of my head when answering this. It'll still be O(1) random access (the `get(int)` of `AbstractSequentialList` forwards to the `listIterator(int).next()` method)

Answer (score 7):

> I know that it's impossible to have a class working like both `List` and `Set`

Have you tried [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)? Technically it's a set but it preserves order which might be just enough for you. However access by index is linear and not built-in.

Other approach would be to wrap `List` with a custom *decorator* that both delegates to `List` and maintains a n internal`Set` for faster `contains`.

Comment: +1 or LinkedHashMap --both are good if memory isn't a concern

Comment: He specifies he needs the `List` interface for access by index (though, unless he's using ArrayList it's not going to be O(1))

Answer (score 1):

What about a `BiMap<Integer, MyClass>`?  This can be found in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

```
BiMap<Integer, MyClass> map = HashBiMap.create();

//store by index
map.put(1, myObj1);

//get by index
MyClass retrievedObj = map.get(1);

//check if in map
if ( map.containsValue(retrievedObj) ) {
   //...
}
```

I know it doesn't implement the `List` interface.  The major limitation here is that insertion and removal are not provided in the traditional `List` sense; but you didn't specifically say whether those were important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons TreeList should do the trick:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: It should, but maybe it doesn't. The documentation states nothing about nothing about `contains`.

Comment: Looking at the source code plus some individual tests indicates that `contains` on a `TreeList` is at best a linear time operation in the worst case (where the element is not in the list).  I haven't thoroughly analyzed it to figure out what it actually is, but it might be slightly worse than that.  In my tests, both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` have significantly faster performance for the `contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a List and Set. This will give you fast indexed lookup and contains (with a small overhead)

BTW: If your list is small, e.g. 10 entries, it may not make any difference to use a plain List.

Comment: I am always intrigued by this "if your list is small" thing. In all the cases so far where I thought it was a small list, someone in the future went and put 10 million elements in it.

Comment: @trejkaz there collections e.g. listeners where if you have large number you are doing something wrong. Storing listeners in a set makes the normal use case expensive and in the case there the developer is doing something wrong you might just be hiding the fact they are doing something wrong. There are times when it makes sense to be prescriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I think a class that wraps a `HashMap` and `List` (as you said in your post) is probably the best best for fast `contains` and `access`.